# JAVA_OPTS for GraalVM static native image

Tags: graalvm-native-image

We are creating static native images which are generated as explained in this article https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/StaticImages/

We are able to run the native image smoothly but we are not able to pass JAVA_OPTS in the ENTRYPOINT of Dockerfile as the image does not have a shell.

Comment: What is your programming language, I see a bug https://www.graalvm.org/release-notes/release-candidates/#:~:text=and%20JAVA_OPTS%20do%20not%20work%20in%20any%20released%20configuration

Comment: programming language is JAVA